# How to make ANE that accesses GooglePlay GameServices

Tags: android, air, google-play-games

I develop AdobeAIR App for Android. 
So, I try to make ANE（ActionScript Native Extensions）that accesses GooglePlay GameServices.
But, it is now working because of the following problem.

[Error]

```
07-22 11:22:44.976: W/Bundle(24987): Key com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1069)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at abh.a(SourceFile:137)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at ato.a(SourceFile:450)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:2257)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 11:22:44.991: W/Bundle(24987):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

[Cause]

- This error attributes to write appid-number directly to
  Manifest-file(XXXX-app.xml) of AIR APP. →If I develop
  native-app(Java) , I refer to「res」folder（res/values/string.xml）. 
  But, AIR App can't read the 「res」folder explicitly, so I have no
  other choice.（correct?）

Ex.)

```
(XXXX-app.xml)
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="123456789012" />     
    </application>
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
```

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add a backslash-space at the start of your android:value like so:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ 123456789012" />
```

This is because the id is expected as a string, but entering just "123456789012" will be interpreted as an integer from XML.

Comment: This causes a different error because it adds a space, making the value non numeric:
**** APP ID IS NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
    **** Application ID ( 782959384988) must be a numeric value.
    **** Please verify that your manifest refers to the correct project ID.