# Android AIR ANE How do I get packaged files in the native layer?

Tags: java, android, air

I'm building a Flash AIR application for Android, as part of the ANE I want to package all of the files that the ANE will need. As expected, when the application is installed on a device, all of these additional assets end up in the ANE directory (the path that you get from getExtensionDirectory() ).

I need to access one of those files in the native Android Java code part of the ANE at runtime. However nothing seems to be able to even find this file on the device when I try to find it. I only have the "app:/..." path provided by the above getExtensionDirectory() call.

Assuming I can get a path...
Sample Path: path = ExtensionContext.getExtensionDirectory().url + "/assets/importantfile.xml"

How do I access this file from within the Android native layer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ANE that accesses GooglePlay GameServices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779245/how-to-make-ane-that-accesses-googleplay-gameservices)